# React app deployed to GCP: App-Engine vs Cloud Storage

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We have a React web-app (a simple admin-console for a mobile app) and we want to deploy it into GCP. We are researching the most efficient way to do this and it appears we can get this done using GCP's App-Engine service, or using GCP Cloud Storage. We are a little unclear as to why choose one over the other?  Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine serves, usually, web site, front end and backend. If you only have a front end you can use App Engine, or serve directly the statics file from Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

The differences

*HTTP serving mode*

- Because App Engine exposes web services, an HTTPS URL is provided. This serving is free!
- GCS serve static files in HTTP mode. No HTTPs available except if you plug an global HTTPS Load Balancer in front of it (about $16 per month)

*Global availability*

- GCS, especially in multi-regional class, is.... multiregional. If you set cache control metadata on GCS, GCS can act as a CDN. Of course, if you use a global HTTPS Load balancer in front of GCS, you can use the load balancer CDN feature.
- App Engine is mono region and doesn't offer cache (CDN) capabilities. However, you can now plug a global HTTPS load balancer in front of App Engine to use the CDN feature of the load balancer -> But in this case, no advantage compare to GCS

Answer (score 0):

App Engine is intended for any dynamic web sites/apps using as backend any App Engine supported languages like Python, Java, NodeJS and [some others](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#the_app_engine_environments).

On the other hand, Cloud Storage can host an [static website](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#static-site) which means it only has static content like HTML, CSS, JS and images.

Having said that and suspecting your web-app can be using NodeJS, your best option would be App Engine.

Something important to add is that also App Engine can host [static websites](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) but in general cost more than Cloud Storage.

Finally, I think [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview) can help you to make the best decision according to your needs.